# ERRO expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token

Tags: c

estou tendo problemas com esse erro...ele aparece somento quando tento usar numa função
, codigo :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char texto[100];
    int i, j, contador;
    char numeros[] = { '0' , '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' , '6' , '7' , '8' , '9' };

}digitos;
    
void qtd_dig(digitos *d)    
 {   
    scanf("%[^\n]*c",(*d).texto);
    (*d).contador=0;
    
    for ((*d).i=0;(*d).i<strlen((*d).texto);(*d).i++){
        for ((*d).j=0;(*d).j<strlen((*d).numeros);(*d).j++){
            if ((*d).texto[(*d).i] == (*d).numeros[(*d).j]){
                (*d).contador++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if ((*d).contador == 1){
        printf ("1 digitos\n");
    }else{
        printf ("%d digitos\n", (*d).contador);
    }
} 

int main(void){

    digitos d;
    qtd_dig(&d);
}
```

ja tentei de tudo mas ainda não consegui resolver, fiz o codigo sem as funções. Mas quando editei adicionando-as ele fica aparecendo esses erros. Alguma ajuda?

erros que aparecem :

- prog.c:8:20: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘**attribute**’
  before ‘=’ token
  char numeros[] = { '0' , '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' , '6' , '7' , '8' , '9' };

  ```
               ^
  ```
- prog.c: In function ‘qtd_dig’: prog.c:18:41: error: ‘digitos {aka
  struct }’ has no member named ‘numeros’
  for ((*d).j=0;(*d).j<strlen((*d).numeros);(*d).j++){

  ```
                                    ^
  ```
- prog.c:19:43: error: ‘digitos {aka struct }’ has no member
  named ‘numeros’
  if ((*d).texto[(*d).i] == (*d).numeros[(*d).j]){

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

As declarações de struct, não suportam inicialização das variáveis. por isso que erro de sintaxe na inicialização do vetor números. A solução seria declarar sem os valores, e depois preencher os dados.
ex:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char texto[100];
    int i, j, contador;
    char numeros[10] ;

}digitos;
    
...


    digitos d;
    int i ;
    char *numeros[]   = { "0" , "1" , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' , '6' , '7' , '8' , '9' };
    for (i=0 ; i<10; i++){
        d.numeros[i]=numeros[i];
    }
```